# 'glewGetContext' was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, undefined, glew

I keep getting an error that states `glewGetContext` was not declared when initializing GLEW. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you `#define` Glew?

Comment: check the Path of header file...

Answer (score 1):

Because you used MX version of GLEW.
You need to define this function yourself

http://glew.sourceforge.net/advanced.html
"Define a macro or function called glewGetContext() that returns a pointer to the GLEWContext object associated with the rendering context from which OpenGL/WGL/GLX calls are issued. This dispatch mechanism is primitive, but generic."

Comment: It doesn't explain well how to create/use this function/macro.